# How to check the saved Azure spatial anchor via Azure portal

Tags: hololens, azure-spatial-anchors

I save the anchor to the cloud and how to use the Azure portal to check the saved anchor?
Thanks.

YL

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Are you just looking at the portal to see the graph indicate that the anchor was created or are you expecting to get additional details about the actual pose information about the anchor itself?

Comment: I would like to check if the anchor has been saved in the cloud. But it will be great if I can look into the details of the anchors such as the pose information.

Answer (score 2):

ASA work like this:  you first create an anchor in your platform's AR system, and then create a cloud counterpart.

You can check different graphs in Azure Portal - ASA resource - Overview tab - Monitoring : Anchors created/updated/deleted & Poses found.

You can't access pose information from Azure portal. You can query those in your code with something like this:

```
Pose anchorPose = currentCloudAnchor.GetPose();
    feedback.text = "Anchor Position: " + anchorPose.position + " Rotation: "
```

Comment: Can I check the ID of the cloud anchor because I need it to locate the anchor?

Comment: yes, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/how-tos/create-locate-anchors-unity#locate-a-cloud-spatial-anchor You need to store first your IDs locally,  in order to locate them later.